# Caption Centered but Table is not

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

For some reason the caption is aligned in the center of the page but the table is too far to the right. How can I have both centered?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{X \\ Y}
\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{l rlrlrl }

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Model 2}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Model 3} \\

\midrule
\midrule

Variable Variable Variable 1 (Variable) Variable & 17.122 & * &   3.481 &* & 0.138 &* \\

\end{tabular}
Note: XYZ
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Leave a blank line between `\end{tabular}` and `Note: XYZ`. Also it wouldn't use `\smallskip` before `tabular`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table and `Note: XYZ` are on the same line and so are centred together. If you do not want that, put a blank line between them and they will each be centred individually.[image]

If your text is too wide (as shown in the edited question) then you need to limit the widths of the columns, for example you can use a `p` column of a fixed width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{X \\ Y}
\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{5cm} rlrlrl }

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Model 2}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Model 3} \\

\midrule
\midrule

Variable Variable Variable 1 (Variable) Variable &
 17.122 & * &   3.481 &* & 0.138 &* \\    
\end{tabular}

Note: XYZ

X\dotfill X
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My edit did not load in time. The problem is the variable names I have are long, and for some reason, even after the fix above the table is still off to the right.

Comment: @CJ12 updated answer